# Is there an equivalent to the WoW armory for Diablo?

Tags: diablo-iii, world-of-warcraft

As a WoW player I am used to being able to view my toon online in the armory and check achievements, etc.

Is there an equivalent for Diablo III toons?

I'm about change my logged in battle.net profile to my Diablo battle tag however I can't see a way to view my toon.

Comment: Interesting... I made a question just like this, but looks like it got deleted for some reason o.O (noticed now).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, as of a recent update there is an equivalent for Diablo III. Once you log into the [battle.net Diablo III site](http://battle.net/d3), you can click the "profile" link under your chosen account to display your career and individual heroes, as well as visit your friends' career / heroes pages.